# Plotting in Python using parallel processors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, parallel-processing, large-data

I have large data sets of positions (x,y,z) in a bounded region in large number of files. I would like to plot them in a 3d plot and I was wondering is there a way to do it parallely. Doing both: reading file and plotting (since it is an bounded region) both in parallel processors.

Comment: Not really if it's not supported within matplotlib. Of course you could read files in parallel and every core is plotting **his points** to the same figure. But without any internal support from matplotlib, this will not pay off (only if there are very heavy calculations before passing to matplotlib, if it's not crashing). Also: i don't think processing-power is the bound while reading files (HDD is just too slow, even SSDs).

Comment: @sascha thanks for your reply. Can you please explain how can all data be read in multiple processors and combined to send it to one processors when it can be plotted ?

Comment: Why would you do that? It will (probably) be slower than single-core reading!

Comment: @sascha: ok thanks